# Tensorflow hangs when initializing large matrix with variable.Whats the best solution for handling large matrix multiplication in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, ubuntu-16.04, tensorflow

I am trying to model a neural network using tensorflow.
But the matrices are in the order of 800000x300000.When I initialize the variables using global variable initializer in tensorflow, the system freezes. How to do deal with this problem?
Could tensorflow with gpu support will be able to handle this large matrix?

Comment: Please show us some code

Answer (score 0):

You can  divide data set into batches and then process you model or you can use tensor flow queue

Comment: But how to initialize this large matrix with variables containing weights? The system freezes when I try to do it.

Comment: The link you shared deals with feeding data iteratively. I am asking about initializing variables.